# Why does ResolveBundleUrl not work for custom folders? (MVC Beta 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

From a brand-new ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta Web Application, I'm re-arranging my folders to match Rob Conery's [VidPub.Web example](https://github.com/tekpub/mvc3/tree/master/Source/VidPub.Web)

Specifically, this means that the final directory structure for content looks like this

```
VidPub.Web
 |
 ---Public
    |
    |---Images
          |--- *.png 
    |---javascripts
          |--- *.js 
    |---stylesheets
         |----themes
              |---base  
                  |--- images
                  |--- *.css
        |----site.css
```

However, when I change the following lines in  `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
           "~/Content/css")" 
           rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" />

<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
           "~/Content/themes/base/css")" 
           rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" />

<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
             "~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
           "~/Public/stylesheets/css")"
           rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" />

<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
           "~/Public/stylesheets/themes/base/css")" 
           rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" />

<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(
           "~/Public/javascripts/js")"></script>
```

I end up with absolutely nothing in the resulting HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script></script>
```

Why isn't it picking up the files in their new locations?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Under `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs` use `BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();` instead of `BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();`

If you look at the source for `RegisterTemplateBundles` you can see that it actually only looks for (and adds) specific js and css files. `EnableDefaultBundles`on the other hand does pretty much the same as when you add you own bundles.

Comment: WOW! Totally life saver... I think I need to add a comment in this post http://dotnet.learningtree.com/2012/03/26/streamlined-web-loading-in-the-visual-studio-11-beta/ to let the author know about this.

Comment: You can read more about this in his blog post: http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/bundling-of-css-and-javascript-in-mvc-4-beta/

Comment: Question: Why doesn't it work when you add all your css files to a folder in Content/Themes/default/css ?

Answer (score 21):

It appears you have to register your own bundle when using non-default directories. I added the following to `Application_Start` and it fixed the problem

```
var bundle = new Bundle("~/Public/stylesheets/css", new CssMinify());
bundle.AddDirectory("~/Public/stylesheets", "*.css", true);
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);

bundle = new Bundle("~/Public/javascripts/js", new JsMinify());
bundle.AddDirectory("~/Public/javascripts", "*.js", true);
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
```

Comment: With _Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.0.0-beta2_ you replace `new Bundle(..., new CssMinify())` to `StyleBundle` and `new Bundle(..., new JsMinify())` to `ScriptBundle`.

Comment: With *Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.0.0-beta2* it seems like AddDirectory is no longer a supported method on Bundle.

So what's the new fix?