# Where can I find the source for System.Web.Optimization?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I am trying to figure out why when I create a scriptbundle that is referencing files that are in an IIS VirtualDirectory under my main site's application folder, why it won't output anything.

I found this post:

[Why does ResolveBundleUrl not work for custom folders? (MVC Beta 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647585/why-does-resolvebundleurl-not-work-for-custom-folders)

but it no longer seems valid with the latest beta build of System.Web.Optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Web.Optimization` is still in the process of being moved to open source, so you can't find the official sources currently.

Comment: Any estimate on when it will be made available?

Comment: I don't have a specific date at this time, but you can use tools like ILSpy to disassembly to effectively look at the source already.

Comment: thanks. I downloaded and ran ILSpy. I've tried to figure out why my bundles in iis virtual directories are not rendering, but it's hard mentally walking all that code that so much is internal and so much resolving paths and urls over and over. How can I get a pdb for System.Web.Optimization so that I can step through and figure out why it won't render my script tags?

Comment: Its probably easists if you just update this question with some code snippets, mostly around how you register your bundle and how you are rendering it on the page, I can probably immediately tell you what's wrong :)

Comment: Thanks, I did reply to you with a code snippet in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100524/how-do-i-get-system-web-optimization-bundles-to-work-with-custom-folders-in-an-i

Comment: That's the bundle registration side, how are you referencing the bundle in your pages?

Comment: "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" .  I finally got it working but I had to modify System.Web.Optimization.  My answer is in that other post.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone stumbling upon this question, the source can now be found at [AspNetWebOptimization](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebOptimization).

Comment: it's on github after codeplex closing
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebOptimization

Answer (score 9):

It's still not currently available, but it will eventually be hosted on the [ASP.NET Optimization CodePlex site](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest).